# How comes the offset in my Postprocess Shader in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, directx, hlsl

I'm implementing a postprocess shader in XNA 4.0. I realized that the original picture (output of the scene renderer) is moved by a tiny distance. It becomes very obvious when I tried to implement a MotionBlur effect. See the image. The output of the scene renderer is a clear yellow cross in the center. After applying the MotionBlur, the image become blur (I didn't move anything in the scene, so the yellow cross should be clear as the original one). I'm very confused. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

(Well, I cannot upload images by far...)

Here's the code snippet of the MotionBlur program:

```
protected void CreateQuad() {
        m_vertex = new VertexPositionTexture[4];
        m_vertex[0] = new VertexPositionTexture(
            new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector2(1, 0));
        m_vertex[1] = new VertexPositionTexture(
            new Vector3(1, -1, 1), new Vector2(1, 1));
        m_vertex[2] = new VertexPositionTexture(
            new Vector3(-1, 1, 1), new Vector2(0, 0));
        m_vertex[3] = new VertexPositionTexture(
            new Vector3(-1, -1, 1), new Vector2(0, 1));
        m_vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(
            m_game.GraphicsDevice, 
            typeof(VertexPositionTexture), 
            4, 
            BufferUsage.None);
        m_vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionTexture>(m_vertex);
    }
    protected void CreateRenderTarget() {
        m_color = new RenderTarget2D(m_game.GraphicsDevice,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);
        m_accColorRead = new RenderTarget2D(
            m_game.GraphicsDevice,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);
        ClearRenderTargetContent(m_accColorRead);
        m_accColorWrite = new RenderTarget2D(
            m_game.GraphicsDevice,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
            m_game.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight);
    }
    public void DoRender(GameTime _gameTime, DebugScene _debugScene) {
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(m_color);
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Blue);
        _debugScene.DoRender(_gameTime);
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        m_effect.CurrentTechnique = m_effect.Techniques["Main"];
        // write to acc
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(m_accColorWrite);
        m_effect.Parameters["ColorMap"].SetValue((Texture2D)m_color);
        m_effect.Parameters["AccColorMap"].SetValue((Texture2D)m_accColorRead);
        m_effect.Parameters["gBlurIntensity"].SetValue(0.9f);
        m_effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes["Blur"].Apply();
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        DrawQuad();
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        // output
        m_game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        m_effect.Parameters["ColorMap"].SetValue((Texture2D)m_accColorWrite);
        m_effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes["Final"].Apply();
        DrawQuad();
        // swap
        RenderTarget2D tmp = m_accColorRead;
        m_accColorRead = m_accColorWrite;
        m_accColorWrite = tmp;
    }
```

Here's the code of MotionBlur shader:

```
texture ColorMap;
sampler ColorMapSampler = sampler_state
{
   Texture = <ColorMap>;
   MinFilter = Linear;
   MagFilter = Linear;
   MipFilter = Linear; 
   AddressU = Clamp;
   AddressV = Clamp;
};

texture AccColorMap;
sampler AccColorMapSampler = sampler_state
{
   Texture = <AccColorMap>;
   MinFilter = Linear;
   MagFilter = Linear;
   MipFilter = Linear;
   AddressU = Clamp;
   AddressV = Clamp;
};

float gBlurIntensity;
struct VS_OUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUT VS(float4 pos : POSITION, float2 tex : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VS_OUT Out = (VS_OUT)0;
    Out.Pos = pos;     
    return Out;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUT IN) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(ColorMapSampler, IN.Tex);
    float4 accColor = tex2D(AccColorMapSampler, IN.Tex);
    return lerp(color, accColor, gBlurIntensity);
}

float4 PS_Final(VS_OUT IN) : COLOR
{
    return tex2D(ColorMapSampler, IN.Tex);
}
technique Main
{
pass Blur
{
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VS();
        ZEnable = false;
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = None;
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS();
}
    pass Final
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VS();
        ZEnable = false;
        ZWriteEnable = false;
        AlphaBlendEnable = false;
        CullMode = None;
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS_Final();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly because you're failing to account for the offset between texels and pixels.  See [this article](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/) for details.

Comment: @ColeCampbell thank you. I've never notice this problem before. Now it works.